# how to filter private properties with TypeORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm using Nodejs, Typescript, Postgres and TypeORM. Since it's a collaborative project, I'm aiming to protect the data that shouldn't be changed by making all my class properties `private`.

```js
@Entity("Car")
export class Car {
    @Column({ name: "name"})
    private _name: string;

    ....
```

When I search in my database for a `Car` which have a specific `name`, I receive this error message : **"Property "name" was not found in "Car". Make sure your query is correct."**

My only way to solve this problem is to make my properties `public` or `readonly` (but sometimes I need to change the value of the property and readonly doesn't allow it so I cannot use it).

Cannot we not use Typeorm with private Typescript properties ?

Answer (score 0):

The properties of your `Entity` should be `public`, since you would use them to **query your data** and to **store information** in the database (you can [check the docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/entities) in order to understand the concept better). You can use the **façade pattern**, in case you want to expose certain data of your API if you really need to, or you can try to add `getters` and `setters` to the class, in order to manipulate such values indirectly. For example:

```
@Entity("Car")
export class Car {
    @Column({ name: "name"})
    private _name: string;

    ....
    
    public setName(name: string) {
       this._name = name;
    }
    
    public getName(): strintg {
       return this.name
    }
```

You really shouldn't take this approach and follow what's stablished on the docs. However, if you decide to take it, try to avoid using `TS` `getters` and `setters` since they have additional implications.